# Threejs object Translate and restore

Tags: three.js, collada

I am new to Three.js. I have loaded a collada (.dae) file having multiple objects. 
Now I want to translate each object on its z axis while on mouse over and restore its position when mouse left that object.

I am using "Raycaster" for this purpose.

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize());
mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
```

and the function is

```
function onDocumentMouseMove ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    // console.log(scene);
    var intersect = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children[2].children);
    // console.log(intersect);
    if ( intersect.length > 0 ) 
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

I have the object where my mouse is intersecting but I'm not sure how to translate the object and restore it on mouse out so it looks smooth.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

You need to move your intersect check out of your `onDocumentMouseMove` and check on your loop. `onDocumentMouseMove` will be called only when your moves moves, but the check will be called every frame.

Your loop should look contain the following:

```
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
var intersect = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

if ( intersect.length > 0 ) {
    intersect[0].object.translateZ(1);
} else  {
    // For all of your objects:
    cube.position.z = 0;
}
```

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/NvBqpz).

Comment: it works but it is not smooth . i mean if mouse still moves on the object (which is translated). object starts blinking. Is there any way to make it a smooth translation.